# Fill arbitrary 2D shape with given set of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a set of rectangles and arbitrary shape in 2D space. The shape is not necessary a polygon (it may be a circle), and rectangles have different widths and heights. The task is to approximate the shape with rectangles as close as possible. I can't change rectangles dimensions, but rotation is permitted.

It sounds very similar to [packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) and covering problem but covering area is not rectangular...

I guess it's NP problem, and I'm pretty sure there should be some papers that show good heuristics to solve it, but I don't know what to google? Where should I start?

**Update:** One idea just came into my mind but I'm not sure if it's worth investigating. What if we consider bounding shape as a physical mold filled with water. Each rectangle is considered as a positively charged particle with size. Now drop the smallest rectangle to it. Then drop the next by size at random point. If rectangles too close they repel each other. Keep adding rectangles until all are used. Could this method work?

Comment: Are you trying to pack as densely as possible? Or approximate the shape as best as possible?  Is there a mathematical function you are trying to optimize, or is it more aesthetic?

Comment: About this charged rectangle method, it might not necessarily give the optimal configuration because we use randomization to drop them at first.

Comment: What is the priority - tracing the boundary or filling the shape? I mean, is it okay if the rectangles trace the boundary perfectly but leave a hole in the middle somewhere?

Comment: @CuriousG Which solution did you end up with?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you could look for packing and automatic layout generation algorithms. Automatic VLSI layout generation algorithms might need similar things, just like textile layout questions...

This paper [Hegedüs: Algorithms for covering polygons by rectangles](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/001044858290104X) seems to address a similar problem. And since this paper is from 1982, it might be interesting to look at the [papers which cite this one](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&hl=en&as_sdt=2000&sciodt=2000&cites=11093890509873644341). Additionally, [this meeting](http://www.dagstuhl.de/programm/kalender/semhp/?semid=28441) seems to be discussing research problems related to this, so might be a starting point for keywords or names who do research in this idea.

I don't know if the computational geometry research has algorithms for your specific problem, or if these algorithms are easy/practical enough to implement. Here is how I would approach it if I had to do it without being able to look up previous work. This is just a direction, by far not a solution...

Formulate it as an optimization problem. You have discrete variables of which rectangles you choose (yes or no) and continuous variables (location and orientation of the triangles). Now you can set up two independent optimizations: a discrete optimization which picks the rectangles; and a continuous that optimizes for the location and orientation once rectangles are given. Interleave these two optimizations. Of course the difficulty lies in the formulation of optimizations, and designing your error energy such that it does not get stuck in some strange configurations (local minima). I'd try to get the continuous as a [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) problem such that I can use standard optimizations libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I think this problem is suitable for solving with genetic algorithm and/or evolutionary strategy algorithm. I've done similar box packing problem with the help of evolutionary strategy algorithm of some kind. Check this out [in my blog](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2008/04/selfish-gene-algorithm.html).

So if you will use such approach - encode into chromosomes box:

- x coordinate
- y coordinate
- angle

Then try to minimize such fitness function-

> y = w1 * box_intersection_area +
>   w2 * box_area_out_of_shape +
>   w3 * average_circle_radius_in_free_space

Choose weights w1,w2,w3 such as to affect importance of factors. When genetic algorithm will find partial solution - remove boxes which still overlaps together or are out of shape - and you will have at least legal (but not necessary optimal) solution.

good luck in this interesting problem !

Answer (score 2):

It is NP hard indeed and since it has hi-tech application, reasonably efficients approximate strategies are not even in patents, let alone published papers.

The best you can do with a limited budget is to start by limiting the problem. Assume that all rectangles are exactly the same, Assume that all rectangles which are binary sub-divisions of your standard rectangle are also allowed since you can efficiently pre-pack them to fit your core division. For extra points you can also form several fixed schemas for gluing core rectangles to cover a few larger shapes with substantially different proportions. Assume that you can change dimensions of your standard rectangle/cell as long as the rest (pre-packing  and gluing schema) remains the same - this gives you parameters to decide approximate size of the core rectangle based on rectangles you are given.

Now you can play with aspect ratios to approximate the error such limited system could guarantee. For the first iterations assume that it can have 50% error with a simple sub-division schema and then change schema to reduce the error but without increasing asymptotic complexity of pre-packing. At the end of the day you are always just assigning given rectangles to your pre-calculated and now fixed grid and binary sub-divisions - meaning you are not trying to do a layout or backtrack at all - you are always happy with the first approximate fit into the grid.

Work on defining classes of rectangles that pack well with your schema - that's again to keep the whole process inverted - you are never trying to actually fit what you are given - you are defining what you have to be given in order to fir it well - then you punt the rest as error since it is approximation.

Then you can try to do a bit more, but not much more - any slip into backtracking or nailing arbitrary small error and it's exponential.

If you are at a research facility and can get some supercomputer time - run a set of exhaustive searches with pathological mixes there just to see how optimal packing may look like and to see if you can derive a few more sub-division schemas and/or classes of rectangle sets.

That should be enough for the first 2 yrs or research :-)