# Resources for optimizing cutting patterns?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a bunch of rectangles of varying dimensions that I need to cutout from a piece of sheet stock.

I'm pretty familiar with python but I've never done anything like this. It seems like a problem that must have been explored before from a computational standpoint, but I'm having a tough time finding any resources.

Is this a classic problem, any recommendations for algorithms I should look into?

Comment: hey Chris, why don't you give this a look over? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516044/fill-arbitrary-2d-shape-with-given-set-of-rectangles

Comment: you should have a much simpler time than that poor fellow who had to deal with an arbitrary base shape. You, on the other hand, are limited to a large rectangle (I assume), ensuring that an optimal solution can be found in reasonable time (gut instinct, no evidence)

Comment: The problem you describe is a two dimensional version of the "bin packing" problem. @Akshaya gave you one reference. Doing a Google search will find many more.

Comment: @JamesThiele is very close, I think. This: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem may be more exactly related to your problem (reducing an NP hard problem to a linear programming one)