# Check whether a 2D shape can be constructed from a set of blocks

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, shapes, plane

I'm looking for an algorithm or a general way for a program to verify whether a certain shape can be constructed from a set of blocks.

For a set of one-line blocks like the one in the example below, it's possible to convert the shape we need into one long line, and write a recursive function for selection of blocks by their length.

[image]

But what is the general way for solving this task (checking the possibility of constructing the shape) with a set containing multi-line blocks, like the 2x2 square in the example below?

[image: example]

Comment: possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516044/fill-arbitrary-2d-shape-with-given-set-of-rectangles

Comment: Perhaps look into a divide and conquer algorithm. If you can find a way to represent areas, you can turn it into a bottom-up dynamic programming solution.

Comment: I understand from your description of the one-line-block method that the blocks cannot be rotated?

Comment: @m69 yes in one-line-block blocks cannot be rotated, so it's easier to solve

Comment: What do the numbers to the right mean?  Do you only have that many copies of each block type?

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, exactly

Comment: Unfortunately that makes the problem much more expensive to solve by the dynamic programming technique I'm thinking of -- instead of needing O(2^n) bits of space, where n is the total number of cells in the grid (this would already limit you to about a 5x5 grid), you'll need O(2^n \* k), where k is the *product* formed by adding one to each piece count and multiplying them together (so, e.g., k=5*7*2=70 for your first example).  Nevertheless I have a simple (but slow) recursion for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this recursively is to start with the initial grid of black and white cells, repeatedly determine a specific black grid cell, and try to cover (or "nibble off") that grid cell with a piece in all possible ways.  For example: Always choose the bottommost, rightmost black grid cell -- that is, among all bottommost black cells in the current subproblem, pick the rightmost.

Some (in practice, most) placements of a piece that cover the chosen cell can be immediately recognised as invalid because they also cover some white cell -- and we know that all white cells must remain white.  If there is no "good" placement of any available piece (a placement is "good" if it covers the chosen cell and no white cells) then we can return NO for this subproblem: It's not possible to solve.  OTOH if there is at least one "good" placement of an available piece, it might or might not lead to a solution: to handle this, each such "good" placement generates a subproblem in which the black cells corresponding to that placed piece have been *deleted* (i.e., turned white), and the number of available pieces of the just-placed piece type has been decreased by one.  A base case occurs when there are no black cells left: we can return YES in this case, since we know it's possible to place pieces to achieve an empty grid (specifically, this involves placing no pieces at all).

This recursive approach potentially revisits some subproblems many times.  For example, if part of the original grid contains a 4x2 block of black cells and you have at least the following 2-cell pieces available:

```
XX  2         Y  2
              Y
```

then you could fill that 4x2 block in the following ways

```
XXYY       YXXY       YYXX
XXYY       YXXY       YYXX
```

so the resulting subproblem (which lacks this 4x2 block and has 2 less of each type of piece) would be solved 3 different times.  To avoid this, under certain (fairly restrictive) circumstances you could use top-down dynamic programming (also known as memoisation).  This has the effect of solving each subproblem at most once, but (potentially) requires storing answers (each a single bit, indicating YES or NO) to *all possible* subproblems, of which there are 2^(m*n)*(k_1+1)*(k_2+1)*...*(k_t+1), where m and n are the width and height of the grid and k_1, ..., k_t are the numbers of available copies of the t different types of piece.  In practice this means that problems larger than about 5*5 will be impractical to solve (at least if you use the "obvious" encoding of the grid, where each cell becomes a single bit in an integer; it's probably possible to come up with a more economical encoding that needs only 2^b bits, where b is the total number of *initially black* cells, instead of the total number of cells overall).  (OTOH, if you're prepared to pretend that there are an unlimited number of each type of piece, you only need to store 2^(m*n) answers, because we don't need to keep track of how many of each piece remain.  This may be useful as a quick first check: If the problem can't be solved even with an unlimited number of each type of piece, then it certainly can't be solved with limited numbers of them.)